# How to spin up spinnaker locally for the first time

Tags: installation, continuous-deployment, spinnaker

How to spin up a local version of Spinnaker? This has been answered and addressed in detail here.

https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/1729

Answer (score 9):

Ok, so I got it to work, but not without you valuable help! @lwander

So I'll leave the steps here for posterity.

Each line is a separate command in the command line, I've installed this on a virtual machine with a freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04 copy with nothing else than SSH. Then SSH as root, You will need to configure sshd on your console to allow root access.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/469143/how-to-enable-ssh-root-access-on-ubuntu-14-04

```
> curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spinnaker/halyard/master/install/stable/InstallHalyard.sh
```

created a user account member of the `adm` and `sudo` groups (is this necessary???)

then Install Halyard:

`bash InstallHalyard.sh`

Verify that `HAL` is installed and validate its version.

`hal -v`

Tell Hal that the deployment type will be as a local instance (this will publish all services in localhost which will be tricky later in order to access them, but I have a turnaround so keep reading)

`hal config deploy edit --type localdebian`

Hal will complain that a version has not been selected, just tell `HAL` which version:

`hal config version edit --version 1.0.0`

The tell `HAL` which storage you are going to use, in my case and since it is local I want to use redis.

`hal config storage edit --type redis`

So now we need to add a cloud provider to `HAL`, we use `AWS` so we add it like this:

`hal config provider aws edit --access-key-id`XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`--secret-access-key`

I created a user on `AWS` and added `access keys` to the user inside `IAM` on the user `security credentials` tab. Obviously my `access-key-id`is not `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`, I edited it. You do not need to enter the `secret-access-key` because the command will prompt for it.

Then you need to create a username relative or that will only concern you spinnaker installation however this will get related to you `AWS` Account-ID, so in MY spinnaker local installation I chose the username `spinnakermaster` you should choose yours!.  And my AWS Account ID is not `YYYYYYYYYYYY`, I've edited too.
All the configurations and steps that you'll need to do inside AWS for this to work are really well documented here:

[https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/providers/aws/](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/providers/aws/
)

And to tell HAL of of the above here's the command:

`hal config provider aws account add spinnakermaster --account-id YYYYYYYYYYYY --assume-role role/spinnakerManaged`

And after all that and if everything went according to plan we can ask HAL to deploy our brand new spinnaker installation.

`hal deploy apply`

It will begin a long installation downloading and configuring all the services.
Once it has finished you may do whatever you like but in my case I created a monitoring script like the one described here:

https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/854

Which can be launched on a recursive manner as this:

`watch -n1 spinnaker-status.sh`or until to`ctrl+C`it!.

then to be able to access your local VM spinnaker copy you can either setup a reverse proxy with the proxy server of your choice to forward all the requests to localhost or you can simply ssh the SH** out of this redirecting the ports;

`ssh root@ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ -L 9000:127.0.0.1:9000 -L 8084:127.0.0.1:8084 -L 8083:127.0.0.1:8083 -L 7002:127.0.0.1:7002 -L 8087:127.0.0.1:8087 -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 -L 8088:127.0.0.1:8088 -L 8089:127.0.0.1:8089`

Where obviously the`ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ` is not an actual IP Address.

And finally to begin having fun with this cutie you have to go to your browser of choice and type into the address bar:

`http://127.0.0.0:9000`

Hope this helps and saves some time to everybody!.

Cheers.

EN

Comment: If I install Spinnaker in EC2 (local Debian). I am aware that I loose distributed benefits, but can I still do everything else, such as applications/pipelines/selection of how many EC2 instances will run on my application?

Comment: be careful with the version. I deployed this on ubuntu 18.04 with lots of extra steps involved.