# WARNING No validation for the AWS provider has been implemented

Tags: amazon-web-services, config, spinnaker

I believe I might be missing a piece here,

I've added the aws account.

```
hal config provider aws account add spinnakermaster \
  --account-id XXXXXXXXXXXX --asume-role role/spinnakerManaged
```

I've added the credentials for the AWS User.

```
hal config provider aws edit --access-key-id XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX --secret-access-key
```

And prompted to its corresponding secret-access-key.

I've edited in the `.hal` directory the `config` file:

```
aws:
      enabled: false
      accounts:
      - name: spinnakermaster
        requiredGroupMembership: []
        accountId: 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
        regions: []
        assumeRole: role/spinnakerManaged
      primaryAccount: spinnakermaster
      accessKeyId: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      secretAccessKey: YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
      defaultKeyPairTemplate: '{{name}}-keypair'
      defaultRegions:
      - name: Canada
      defaults:
        iamRole: BaseIAMRole
```

And I am deploying Spinnaker with AWS support which execute with one hiccup:

```
Problems in default.provider.aws.spinnakermaster:
- WARNING No validation for the AWS provider has been
  implemented.
```

Which step/info/config am I missing.

Regards
EN

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: I did, and shared my steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44466215/how-to-spin-up-spinnaker-locally-for-the-first-time/44466216#44466216

Answer (score -1):

updated. This warning is OK and will not affect your executions. 
My suggestions after installing Spinnaker in EC2 local debian, Azure AKS and Minnaker on EC2.

- Please dont install a microservice architecture in a monolith environment such as local Debian. It doesnt work
- At All Cost Focus on the correct AWS Managed and Managing IAM structure. Please Follow Armory Spinnaker instructions on how to achieve this [Armory IAM structure](https://docs.armory.io/spinnaker-install-admin-guides/add-aws-account-iam/)

---

Previous misleading answer: As of Now Spinnaker version 1.16.4 and based on the official documentation. There are 2 ways to manage the AWS infrastructure:

1. with aWS key and secret
2. with IAM role attached to the AWS EC2 instance running the spinnaker.

This error usually comes up when halyard cannot recognize the Key and secret for the corresponding account. [Check halyard Code Documentation](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=spinnaker%2Fhalyard%2Fhalyard-master%2Fhalyard-config%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fnetflix%2Fspinnaker%2Fhalyard%2Fconfig%2Fvalidate%2Fv1%2Fproviders%2Faws%2FAwsAccountValidator.java)

One way to resolve it depending on your deployment type is adding an AWS account with the corresponding Key and Secret values. [Check Halyard add-account](https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/halyard/commands/#hal-config-provider-aws-account-add)

[Documentation AWS Cloud Provider](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/providers/aws/aws-ec2/)